# Does Nvidia Cuda warp Scheduler yield?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, schedule

I have gone through [Cuda programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) but still not clear whether a warp will yield in favor of other ready-to-execute warp? Any explanation or pointer please? If yes, in what condition does a warp yield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the on-chip scheduler interleaves the execution of warps.  The scheduling policy is intentionally left unspecified, because the scheduling policy may be changed.  NVIDIA does not want CUDA developers to write code that relies on the current scheduling policies but fails on newer GPUs.

Generally speaking, the purpose of having multiple warps is that while one thread waits for an instruction to finish executing, another thread may be ready to execute without waiting.  So it is likely that a warp will yield when a long-latency instruction such as a global load or a slow floating-point operation is executed.  Some architectures, such as Fermi, execute multiple warps at the same time ( http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf page 10).

Comment: Actually, it's not just likely, it's almost certain that a warp will yield to another warp after issuing each instruction.  Even simple instructions have non-zero latency.  On Fermi the latency of arithmetic instructions is about 10-12 issue slots, so you want at least that many resident warps.

Comment: Can you point to the resources that implies on Fermi arithmetic instruction latency is about 10-12 issue slots? Or that's what you discovered yourself? Thanks

Comment: The [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) discusses occupancy. Most instructions have a latency of 22 cycles and occupy the SM for 1 to 2 cycles. The manual has some tables. That means you need 11 to 22 concurrent warps per SM to saturate the arithmetic unit.